# Smooth function zero at origin is x times smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request

What’s the name (or reference) for the real-analytic lemma

> A $\mathrm C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbf R\to\mathbf R$ with $f(0) = 0$ is $f(x) = xg(x)$ with $g$ also $\mathrm C^\infty\,$

and the multidimensional variant

> A $\mathrm C^\infty$ function $f:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R$ with $f(0) = 0$ is $f(x) =\sum_i x_ig_i(x)$ with the $g_i$ also $\mathrm C^\infty\,$?

I can easily prove at least the one-dimensional variant using Taylor’s theorem (and actually need the Schwartz function variant, anyway), but I could swear I saw it named somewhere, as an ingredient for either Borel’s theorem on Taylor series or Whitney’s extension theorem.

Comment: You can prove both by looking at $g(t)=f(tx)$ and computing $\int_{0}^{1}g'(t)dt$ in two ways. I don't know who proved this first. I bet Euler knew about it. A far reaching and non-trivial generalization is [Malgrane preparation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgrange_preparation_theorem)

Comment: So my $g_i(x) = \int_0^1 D_i f(tx)dt$ ? That works, thanks! Though it does need a theory of integration...

Comment: These are smooth functions. That's the well-known idea, the same that Euler used to prove his theorem about homogeneous functions, that also solves that exercise.

Comment: @logarithm Sure, I’m only lamenting the need for integration as a prerequisite. And yes, I did miss the connection with the homogeneous function theorem, thanks.

Comment: About https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221221/two-definitions-of-schwartz-space $H_3$ [acts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Representation_theory) on $L^2(R)$ and we have also Haar measure on $H_3$ allowing to define $L^1(H_3)$, then $u \in L^2(R)$ is Schwartz iff for all $f \in L^1(H_3)$, $\Pi(f) u = \int_{H_3} f(g) \Pi(g) u d\mu(g) $ is well-defined $L^2$  and smooth, so that $f \mapsto \Pi(f) u $ is a smooth representation of the convolution algebra $L^1(H^3)$